# Rotating a div how to set around which point to rotate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My javascript is:

```
$(function() {
    var $elie = $(".circle");
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(++degree);
        },5);
    }
});
```

How do I rotate the div around another center point?

Here's demo:

```js
$(function() {
    var $elie = $(".circle");
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(++degree);
        },5);
    }
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px dashed black;
 
  margin: calc(50vh - 100px) auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd use `transform-origin` for that :

```
$elie.css("-webkit-transform-origin", "50% 100%" );
```

or

```
transform-origin: 100% 40%;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% 40%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 40%; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 40%; /* Firefox */
-o-transform-origin: 100% 40%; /* Opera */
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LMyPg/)

---

**EDIT:**

To rotate around the center of the `.circle` element, it first needs a height, otherwise there is no center. Then you could use percentages, or the much handier `center` property, like so:

```
transform-origin:center center;
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LMyPg/2/)

Comment: I want to be rotated as the given example: http://prikachi.com/images/409/5949409Y.png The black dot is the center and the circle should be rotated around it. Any ideas? Btw I'm not good at English and explaining stuffs in english, Sorry!