# Center of the div - center point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I make the center of the div as the center point for the rotation.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204815/rotating-a-div-how-to-set-center-point) while I was doing some research but I can't seem to fit it in to mine.

This is what the post has suggested. But doesn't work.
`$(area).css('-webkit-transform-origin', 'rotate(' + dgR + 'deg)');`

```
function rot(e, area) {
          var offset = area.offset();
          var ceX = (offset.left) + ($(area).width() /2);
          var ceY = (offset.top) + ($(area).height() /2);
          var muX = e.pageX;
          var muY = e.pageY;
          var rdi = Math.atan2(muX-ceX, muY-ceY);
          var dgR = (rdi * (180/Math.PI)*-5);
          $(area).css('transform', 'rotate(' + dgR + 'deg)');
          $(area).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + dgR + 'deg)');
          $(area).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + dgR + 'deg)');
          $(area).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + dgR+'deg)');
}
```

Comment: By default `transform-origin` is at center

Comment: @Ehtesham Yep, of most elements...I'm not sure that's true of SVG as different browsers pick different starting points for those.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the transform-origin incorrect.

```
$(area).css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
```

This should place the rotation origin point in the middle of the `area`

Comment: thanks. What about `'rotate(' + dgR+'deg)'` ? how will that fit in the?

Comment: @Fergoso `transform-origin` just sets the transformation point, you can rotate with a separate `transform` like you're doing in your function

Comment: +10  Ok, How should I set the center point if I'm rotating the images at runtime?

Comment: Just apply it in the same function you do the rotating in right now.

Comment: That's exactly my question. I tried but I was not successful.

Comment: applied your function in an example, without any context it would'nt  even need the above specified line: http://jsfiddle.net/ptLm6nmy/1/ altough something quirky is happening with you calculation.

Answer (score 0):

When I got you right, you just want to rotate a div in it's center point, aren't you? Here you have to define the center point with `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` in your div.

Heres a fiddle to play around (without jscript): http://jsfiddle.net/nub0umft/