# Rotating a div/img with a button issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to rotate a div using html and javascript but I can't get it to rotate in place. As of now it circles the image around in a wide circle all over the page and not in it's original spot. I think it has something to do with me using a div to hold the image. It's like it is making the 0 axis the center of the page but I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
<html>
    <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL                  here" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1"/>
    </form>
        <div id="photo"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';
            });
        </script>
        <button id="button">rotate</button>>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
            var curr_value = document.getElementById('photo').style.transform;
            var new_value = "rotate(30deg)";
            if(curr_value !== ""){
            var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 30;
            new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
            }
            document.getElementById('photo').style.transform = new_value;
            };
        </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to rotate just img in parent 'photo' div like this https://jsfiddle.net/ab5jkybL/

```
        <script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';
            });
        </script>
        <button id="button">rotate</button>>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
                var curr_value = document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform;
                var new_value = "rotate(30deg)";
                if(curr_value !== ""){
                var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 30;
                new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
                }
                document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 you could try this:

```
transform-origin:center center;
```

This should set the center for transforms to the elements own center.
I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204815/rotating-a-div-how-to-set-center-point).

Comment: Well, if you have a css file I would create a rule in there like
    `#photoimg { transform-origin:center center; }`
Otherwise you can use inline css `<img id="photoimg" style="transform-origin:center center;" ....>`
A third way would be to set the attribute via javascript.

Comment: how would you set the attribute via javascript?

Comment: This should do the trick:
`var element = document.getElementById('photoimg')
element.style["transform-origin"] = "center center"`