# translate() seems to cause rotate() to not work right in Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, velocity.js

I am trying to create an animation.  The animation is suppose to be a rocket blasting off of the ground into space.  Once in space a button will be clicked and it will rotate in another direction and blast off in that direction.  The problem I am having is the rotateZ axis seems to stay in the default position while the image is translated into another position before rotating.  So instead of the image just simply rotating to the right, it rotates in a wide circle to the right. I have messed with the background-origin properties to fix this but I cannot get it to work right.

```
var square = $('#square');
var rotate = $('#rotate');

square.velocity({rotateZ: '-90deg'});
square.velocity({translateY: '-10vw',translateX: '50vh'},{duration: 2000});

rotate.click(function(){
    square.velocity({rotateZ: '20deg'});
});
```

Comment: I would venture to say (because I am not familiar with velocity) that it doesn't work because all three of those attributes fall inside the `transform` css property; you may be overwriting that property when the translate call is made. I would try including them in the same call if you can.

Comment: Here is the JS fiddle to show what I am talking about https://jsfiddle.net/hunterjr88/x003mwzy/

Comment: So, what you're saying is the origin of the rotation remains where the div started, but you want to set the origin of the rotation to the center of the div after its transformation? [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204815/rotating-a-div-how-to-set-center-point).

Comment: that is exactly what i want to do.  I read the thread from your link and tried resetting the transform origin with the css() or in velocity we use a hook helper function which does the same thing.  It does not change anything. The origin continues to remain in its original position.

Comment: So i figured out the problem.  I had to end up resetting the position of the div before the second transform affect.  When I reset the position the rotation worked like it should.  I did find some weird occurences when the rotation is set to 0 deg.  I had to set it to at least 1 deg for it to work.  Here is the updated jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/hunterjr88/x003mwzy/2/

Comment: Another thing I realized.  when you reset the position you also have to reset the translate to 0.  That should fix everything.